# Cant execute elasticsearch in qnap. Error with mktemp

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to execute elasticsearch on my qnap server but seems there is a problem creating a temporary directory as I get the following output mktemp: Invalid argument

As I have read opkg busybox mktemp uses a different way to create the dir which conflicts with gnu mktemp of elasticsearch. It could be solved by creating manually an ES_TEMP dir and adding it to the path so that executing elasticsearch skips that step but I don't know how to do it.

Have you had a similar problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that although is not efficient as it needs to be done each time you reboot it works. It is about setting the temp directory manually:

```
export ES_TMPDIR=/tmp
```

This will do the trick